# RSpec failing because URL is being escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, selenium-chromedriver

Moving RSpec in a Rails project from using Poltergeist to using Selenium (Webdriver) Chrome and now I'm getting some failures I wasn't quite expecting. Looks like it's trying to escape the URL for some reason?  Thoughts?

```
Failures:

  1) Story editing private story should be read after editing
     Failure/Error: expect(story_cover_image).to eq "#{url}/convert?rotate=exif"

       expected: "http://placehold.it/edited.png/convert?rotate=exif"
            got: "\"http://placehold.it/edited.png/convert?rotate=exif\""

       (compared using ==)
```

Here's the spec (removed what's not relevant):

```
feature 'Story editing', type: :feature, js: true do
  ...
  let(:story_attributes) do
    {
      ...
      cover_image: {
        url: 'http://placehold.it/edited.png'
      }
    }
  end

  ...

  def fill_file_url(url)
    execute_script <<-JS
      angular.element(".content").scope().story.addCoverImage();
      angular.element(".content").scope().story.coverImage.url = "#{url}";
      angular.element(".content").scope().story.save();
    JS

    expect(story_cover_image).to eq "#{url}/convert?rotate=exif"
  end

  ...

  def fill_in_story_form(story)
    fill_file_url story[:cover_image][:url] if story[:cover_image]
  end

  ...

  context 'private' do
    scenario 'story should be read after editing' do
      fill_in_story_form story_attributes            <<<<<< SPEC FAILS ON THIS LINE >>>>>
      ...
    end
  end
```

**EDIT** New failure after changing `"#{url}"` to `#{url}` as per request:

Also tried: `angular.element(".content").scope().story.coverImage.url = url;`

```
  1) Story editing private story should be read after editing
     Failure/Error:
           execute_script <<-JS
             angular.element(".content").scope().story.addCoverImage();
             angular.element(".content").scope().story.coverImage.url = #{url};
             angular.element(".content").scope().story.save();
           JS

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
         (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
angular.element(".content").scope().story.coverImage.url = "#{url}";
```

Because inside a HEREDOC everything is considered to be a string `#{url}` is all you need to do string interpolation. But in this case you want the interpolation to be treated as a Javascript string so you should use `'#{url}'`. Doing `"#{url}"` creates escaped double-quotes because by default a [HEREDOC follows double-quoting rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents#Double-quoting_rules), so you should change all your double quotes to single quotes inside the HEREDOC.

Trying it directly into the irb console you get:

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
<<-JS
  angular.element('.content').scope().story.coverImage.url = '#{url}';
JS
=> "angular.element('.content').scope().story.coverImage.url = 'https://www.google.com';\n";

<<-JS
  angular.element(".content").scope().story.coverImage.url = '#{url}';
JS
=> "angular.element(\".content\").scope().story.coverImage.url = 'http://www.google.com';\n"
```

[Quoting rules of Heredoc docs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents#Quoting_rules)

Comment: Unfortunately replacing `"#{url}"` with `#{url}` leads to a new error which I've added to end of my question (above).

Comment: @Meltemi, I updated the answer to reflect the new error, use single quotes around the interpolation

Comment: Unfortunately, using `'#{url}'` fails with exact same error as using `"#{url}"` which is: `got: "\"http://placehold.it/edited.png/convert?rotate=exif\""`

Comment: @Meltemi, not sure if i can help you any further, sorry.